# jQuery if statement, syntax

Tags: javascript, if-statement

What is a simple jQuery statement that states an operation proceeds only if A and B are true? If A isn't true, stop.  If A and B are true, then continue.
`

Comment: As asked, this seems a general javascript question -- can you please clarify what's jquery-specific about it?

Comment: My complete call is jQuery...(I'm just using some css rewrites...)

Comment: I hope you realize that jquery is a *library*, and the language still is *javascript*.

Comment: Yes, harshath.jr, I realize that.

Comment: I'm assuming that the OP is looking for something that would lead to a jquery construct like this: 
$(selector).DoIf(function(){return A && B})// continue jquery chaining but actions only happen if the DoIf predicate succeeds

Comment: in which case $(selector).filter(function(index)) can do what he's looking for.

Answer (score 87, accepted):

jQuery is just a library which enhances the capabilities of the DOM within a web browser; the underlying language is JavaScript, which has, as you might hope to expect from a programming language, the ability to perform conditional logic, i.e.

```
if( condition ) {
    // do something
}
```

Testing two conditions is straightforward, too:

```
if( A && B ) {
    // do something
}
```

*Dear God, I hope this isn't a troll...*

Answer (score 10):

You can wrap jQuery calls inside normal JavaScript code. So, for example:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    if (someCondition && someOtherCondition) {
        // Make some jQuery call.
    }
});
```

Answer (score 3):

To add to what the others are saying, A and B can be function calls as well that return boolean values.  If A returns false then B would never be called.

```
if (A() && B()) {
    // if A() returns false then B() is never called...
}
```

Comment: As long as A() doesn't return false or null it will be true.

Answer (score 2):

It depends on what you mean by stop. If it's in a function that can return void then:

```
if(a && b) {
    // do something
}else{
    // "stop"
    return;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
if(A && B){ }
```

Answer (score 0):

I little sophisticated way:

```js
$(selector).is(condition)? alert('true') : alert('false');
```

Ex:

```js
$("#btn-primary").is(":disabled")? alert('button disabled') :  alert('button disabled');
```

Answer (score -1):

If you're using Jquery to manipulate the DOM, then I have found the following a good way to include logic in a Jquery statement:

```
$(selector).addClass(A && B?'classIfTrue':'');
```

Comment: This answer is deviant to the question asked.