# How to combine if and if not

Tags: jquery

I have created a function I want to run if and if something is not true:

```
$(window).width() > 990) 
!$('body').hasClass("home")
```

I have tried the following to combine them:

```
if( $(window).width() > 990) && !$('body').hasClass("home") {
  //my function
}
```

Although I have tried this:

```
if( $(window).width() > 990) || !$('body').hasClass("home") {
  //my function
}
```

How can I combine these?
(Read [check if element does not have class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7841048/how-to-check-if-an-element-does-not-have-a-specific-class) and [if statement syntax](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/885756/jquery-if-statement-syntax))

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue is because you're closing the parenthesis after the first condition. Try this:

```
if ($(window).width() > 990 && !$('body').hasClass("home")) {
   // my function
}
```

I would suggest you use a text editor with syntax highlighting for javascript as it makes it nearly impossible to miss errors like this.

Comment: Damn I hate these… I am using one but it seems as it is not as good. Thanks.